# How to send ajax request to bots business webhook?

Tags: bots.business

Hello I am trying to send ajax request to bb webhook by following code.

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
 url: webhookUrl,
 data: { user_id: YOUR_USER_ID },
 success: success,
 dataType: "json"});
```

Now what bjs i need to execute command by webhook?

Comment: after webhook calling command is executed. Do you want call another command from that command?

Comment: Yes I want another command